# CompletableFuture to execute multiple DB queries asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, parallel-processing, completable-future

I want to execute multiple DB queries parallelly and store the results in a map. I am trying to do it like this but the map is not getting populated completely when I am accessing the map.

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
 public Map<MapKeyEnums, Set<String>> doDBCalls(String phoneNumber, long timestamp) {

         Map<MapKeyEnums, Set<String>> instrumentsEdgesMap = new EnumMap<>(MapKeyEnums.class);

         CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "ABC", timestamp)).
                    thenApply(x -> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(MapKeyEnums.ABC, x));

         CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "XYZ", timestamp)).
                    thenApply(x -> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(MapKeyEnums.XYZ, x));

         CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "DEF", timestamp)).
                    thenApply(x -> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(MapKeyEnums.DEF, x));

         return instrumentsEdgesMap;

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the above approach `supplyAsync` will be executed by the `Async` thread from [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), but `thenApply` method is always executed by calling thread. So your queries will run one after the another in sequence which it is not Asynchronous

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task).

Here is the example

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return "SupplyAsync";
    }).thenAccept(i->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"--"+i);
    });
```

**Output :**

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
main--SupplyAsync
```

So if you want your process to be `Async` then first trigger all three db queries with `supplyAsync` and capture the output within `CompletableFuture`

```
CompletableFuture<Set<String>> first =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "ABC", timestamp));

CompletableFuture<Set<String>> second =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "XYZ", timestamp));

CompletableFuture<Set<String>> third =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "DEF", timestamp));
```

And then now create a stream with three of them and then collect them to `Map`

```
Stream.of(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<MapKeyEnums, CompletableFuture<Set<String>>>(MapKeyEnums.ABC, first),
              new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<MapKeyEnums, CompletableFuture<Set<String>>>(MapKeyEnums.XYZ, second),
              new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<MapKeyEnums, CompletableFuture<Set<String>>>(MapKeyEnums.DEF, third))
       .forEach(entry->{
           entry.getValue().thenAccept(val-> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(entry.getKey(), val));
       });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have to wait for the futures to complete before you return the result.

Try something like

```
    public Map<MapKeyEnums, Set<String>> doDBCalls(String phoneNumber, long timestamp) {

        Map<MapKeyEnums, Set<String>> instrumentsEdgesMap = new EnumMap<>(MapKeyEnums.class);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "ABC", timestamp))
                .thenAccept(x -> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(MapKeyEnums.ABC, x)),

            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "XYZ", timestamp))
                .thenAccept(x -> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(MapKeyEnums.XYZ, x)),

            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbReadService.getCall(phoneNumber, PhoneNumber.class, "DEF", timestamp))
                .thenAccept(x -> instrumentsEdgesMap.put(MapKeyEnums.DEF, x)))
        .get(); // wait for completion of all three subtasks

        return instrumentsEdgesMap;
    }
```

Comment: Should we not use join instead of get if this is the code? If using get, have to explicitly handle the two checked exceptions.

V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException;

Comment: You're right. Depending on your requirements and use case `join` may be the better choice.